# Fundamental theorem of calculus application

Tags: calculus

Given the integral $$\int_b^{\tan x} f(t)~dt$$ where $b$ is a constant, you're meant to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, which I understand, but I encounter problems with the differentiation of $F(\tan x)$.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear my dear sir.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are asking how to calculate:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{c}^{\tan(x)}f(t)dt
\end{align*}

By the first fundamental theorem of calculus, this is equal to:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\big[F(\tan(x)) - F(c)\big]
\end{align*}

Now by the chain rule and the second fundamental theorem of calculus, this is equal to:
\begin{align*}
F'(\tan(x))\tan'(x) - 0 = f(\tan(x))\sec^2(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Yeah I thought (and wrote) the same but "webassign" marked it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> but I encounter problems with the differentiation of $F(\tan x)$.

Alternatively, there is no need to pass via a primitive function $F$. You have (by the [FTOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part)):
$$\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x} \int_c^x f(t)\,\mbox{d}t = f(x)$$
So by the chain rule with $u=\tan x$ (so $\color{red}{u'=\sec^2\!x}$), you simply get:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}x} \int_c^{\tan x} f(t)\,\mbox{d}t 
& = \color{blue}{\frac{\mbox{d}}{\mbox{d}u}}\color{red}{\frac{\mbox{d}u}{\mbox{d}x}} \color{blue}{\int_c^{u} f(t)\,\mbox{d}t} \\[5pt]
&  = \color{blue}{f(u)}\color{red}{\sec^2\!x} \\[5pt]
& = f\left(\tan x\right) \sec^2\!x
\end{align}$$